# Cannot read from file - ferror() returns 1

Tags: c++

First of all, my code was working yesterday.

I have a code to open and read 2 files and write 1.

It's using `fopen_s()` to open all files ("rb" to read and "wb" to write), `fread()` to read and `fwrite()` to write. I also calc the size of the file by pointing to the end and then rewind,
I checked if the FILE * was null and if `errno` was different from 0.
The problem is when I read from the first file he will return 0 and the second will return 4 (the expected).

I checked the first file with `ferror()` and he return 1, `feof()` returns 0.

ferror() return the code error so checked the error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-doserrno-sys-errlist-and-sys-nerr) ("Operation not permitted").

This is not the only function in the same project that have this problem and already tried using different files.

Code (this is some part of the code):

```
FILE * c = NULL;
errno_t error = fopen_s(&c, c_str.c_str(), "rb");
if (c != NULL && error == 0)
{
    FILE * k = NULL;
    error = fopen_s(&k, k_str.c_str(), "rb");
    if (k != NULL && error == 0)
    {
        FILE * f = NULL;
        error = fopen_s(&f, f_str.c_str(), "wb");
        if (f != NULL && error == 0)
        {
            fseek(c, 0L, SEEK_END);
            long size = ftell(c);
            rewind(c);
            size_t read_c = fread(num, sizeof(char), buf_size, c);
            size_t read_k = fread(buf, sizeof(char), buf_size, k);
            if (ferror(c))
            {
                // he enter here returning "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: @BarisYakut done

Comment: Do these files all have names, and are they unique. Furthermore, what is the point of the `f` file management in this code? Finally, have you checked permissions on all related files?

Comment: Note that `fopen_s` is `C` and not `C++`. You are mixing two languages (although you use a `std::string` as it seems. Is there a particular reason you don't use `std::fstream`?

Comment: Please try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code lacks of some important variables

Comment: @WhozCraig They have all different names, and I already checked the permissions, even if the files are in the same directory that happen

Comment: @hellow compatiblity and speed(i think)

Comment: @hellow I added the size calc part. But that's it. It strange since this always worked for me, only now I have this problem.

Comment: I second the request for a [mcve]. Please try to provide the smallest program which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Samega7Cattac Make [something like this](https://pastebin.com/vEN27tmn), make it break, and then tells us *exactly* what conditions made that happen.

Comment: @Yunnosch this is all the code, that's the strange part, should work bc the code it's too simple.

Comment: Please study the provided link. There is no way that the code as shown even compiles, not to speak of being executable. An MCVE has to be buildable into an executable.

Comment: @WhozCraig your code worked and I don't know I, but now I have a clue. Thanks

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1):

The error "Operation not permitted" was not about the file or the function, but the buffer.
I have 2 buffers and I was dividing one size by the 2 but in the function I was passing the sum of the 2.

**Conclusion: Errors returned by file functions aren't always about the file.**

Comment: Thanks to @WhozCraig by giving a clue about it